# Embedded Youtube videos are appearing over my Shadowbox player, can anyone help?

Tags: shadowbox

Hi any help would be greatly appreciated I've tried a bunch of z-index and wmode fixes.  No luck so far.

On my site [www.GeocachersNYC.com](http://geocachersnyc.com)

I have a Tumblr feed on the left that has embedded Youtube videos.  On the right icons that launch youtube videos that play in Shadowbox.  This has always worked fine but after upgrading to CS5 Dreamweaver and uploading the site the embedded videos in the feed appear over the Shadowbox. Seems to be a problem only in Google Chrome, looks fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

If you need me to provide any code just let me know.

Comment: I've had similar problems. I have a shadowbox gallery and a youtube embed on my page. When a picture comes up in shadowbox, the youtube embed remains over the portion of the shadowbox. If you were able to resolve this, please let me know how you were able to. It would be immensely helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Add a wmode=transparent attribute to the end of your embed code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/gfG2hdGiTqs?rel=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" width="525" height="297"></iframe>
```

Here is a document that explains it more in depth: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/float-div-youtube-iframe/